# Creating a GPX String By Iterating Through ArrayList of Custom Location Objects

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, iteration

**THE PROBLEM**

I am currently creating a gpx string by iterating through an array of custom objects called 'CCTrackLocation'. However, this is too slow, especially when there are many locations. I am also running it in an Async Task.

Here is my code.

```
for (CCTrackLocation location: trackLocations) {
            //Log.e("CCGPXUtils", "Time wasting");
            String amendedString = gpxString + "<trkpt lat=\""+location.getLatitude()+"\" lon=\""+location.getLongitude()+"\">\n" +
                                                "<ele>"+location.getAltitude()+"</ele>\n" +
                                                "<time>"+CCDateUtility.convertTimestampIntoGPXFormat(location.getTimestamp())+"</time></trkpt>\n";
            gpxString = amendedString;
            amendedString = null;
```

The first 500 or so points are converted fine, after that I get getting 'GC_FOR_MALLOC' and 'GC_CONCURRENT' coming up in the debug console.

**THE QUESTION**

Is there a more efficient way to do this that won't be so time consuming?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest solution I've found.

I didn't know about 'StringBuilder' due to coming from an Objective-C background but they are the solution to my problem.

Here is my updated code.

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(gpxString);
        for (CCTrackLocation location: trackLocations) {
            if (isCancelled())
                return null;
            //Log.e("CCGPXUtils", "Time wasting");
            stringBuilder.append("<trkpt lat=\""+location.getLatitude()+"\" lon=\""+location.getLongitude()+"\">\n" +
                                                "<ele>"+location.getAltitude()+"</ele>\n" +
                                                "<time>"+CCDateUtility.convertTimestampIntoGPXFormat(location.getTimestamp())+"</time></trkpt>\n");
}
return stringBuilder.toString();
```

**OUTCOME**

The performance has increased 100fold.